# Animation Cycles rendering remains incredible slow

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am a beginner currently working on my first real project. For this project I am required have a cubistic tunnel environment with light on the end. Everything went great until I wanted to make an animation-render [cycles] to with some camera movement to show off the environment as a test. When the rendering started I was shocked to see that each frame took about 4 minutes to render out. As there are 350 frames for this little test I reckoned was doing something wrong so I searched for ways to improve the rendering but to not much result. I am getting really desperate at this point so I would value your input greatly.

Computer: Macbook Pro - M1 - 16GB RAM

I tried with the GPU and CPU both with optimized tile and adaptive sampling at rather low sample settings.

[image]

Comment: you could provide your blend file, so we could have a look at it. But i think - assume - you took too much topology/subdivision surfaces. You can check e.g. by turning on statistics:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imQ8e.png

Comment: hey Chris, you might be on to something. How do I fix this? There is a modifier for this kind of stuff if I am correct right? Vertices 84K, Edges 167k, Faces 83K, Triangles 166k...thanks man

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N-lcnVJ4Z9bvRgUtQsD82U-wrN9gFGqR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NigelGreyDubois Your poly/vertex counts are nothing to be concerned about at a mere ~100k. This isn't really a unique problem you're experiencing. Raytracing is just a very computationally expensive task.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys

Comment: Your expectations are just off. The scene is pretty dark and 4 minutes per frame on this low-end hardware is not that bad. You most likely can optimze the scene to render in 3 minutes but that's it. If you'd like to speed things up, you would have to use a graphics card for rendering (ideally multiple cards). Consider using a render farm in conjunction with your hardware.

Comment: Hey Brockmann, Thanks for the info. I will probably redo the thing in Evee as it seems more suited for this project.

Comment: @NigelGreyDubois Yep, good idea. I guess it still takes 1min per frame when bumping up the settings (contact shadows, gi, lightprobe etc.)... but it should improve performance drastically if you do not need realism.